# Weird Artifacts When Rendering

Tags: rendering, mesh, uv, vertices, artifacts

I am working on a 3d model in blender (obviously). I don't know why, but when I hop into rendered mode, the object has weird triangles on the object.

[image]

I don't know why those are there, but i think it might have something to do with the UVs, but im not sure. What is really weird, though, is that my object doesn't have those triangles as part of the actual mesh. Here is what the mesh looks like in solid rendering mode.

[image]

As you  can see, there is obviously no triangles part of the actual mesh. Any idea on whats going on? Thanks for any answers :)

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you mean by "weird triangles"? Highlighting the problematic areas in your screenshots by using colored circles and boxes really helps reducing the "Where is Waldo" effect. Also consider uploading your file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and put the link in your question.

Comment: Hi, I thing the problematic areas are clearly visible. But for future was better mark them. :-) To the point: Should be best upload .blend, because there are many reasons why this can happen. Now we can only divine.

Comment: Did you try recalculating your normals? Press ctrl+n after selecting verything in edit mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have overlapping geometry - where you have two or more faces overlaying each other. This can have the effect of such artifacts. Try editing your model in wireframe mode (press 'Z' to toggle between wireframe and solid 3d view) and check that you don't have overlapping faces.

Comment: Omg. This was what I needed. I somehow copied 3 planes in the same spot. Thank you!